# Can I leave BL21(DE3) cells in room temperature?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, ecoli

I am preparing competent cells, and I finished inoculating a single colony in SOB. It has been incubating at 37 degrees Celsius for almost 16 hours since, and it's getting very late where I live. I wanted to do the large-scale inoculation a few (at least 7) hours from now instead of right away, but I do not want the cells to start dying. Can I take the cells out of the incubator and leave the cells in room temperature? I'm hesitant about this because even at room temperature, wouldn't cells still be growing, making it possible for cells to die as well? What extra steps, if any, should I take before using the cells?

Comment: Don't do this. User fresh cells thoughout the process, everything else can affect your transformation efficiency in the end.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: I always did the preculture (picking a single colony from the plate) overnight (12-16 hrs typically) and then started the main culture from which I harvest the cells for the competent cells the next morning. Here you need to carefully check the OD anyways to not overgrow the cells.

Comment: I meant to do that, but I end up having to do the preculture in the morning (long story), so now I feel like I should either start harvesting or (as someone suggested to me) leave it in room temperature.

Comment: I would use a fresh overnight culture then. A colleague tested this a while ago and the cells which are stored for a while give less efficient transformation rates.

Comment: What kind of inoculation? What is the final purpose? It may not be a problem at all. Ask someone in your lab to take the cells out and keep them in 4⁰C

Comment: If you leave the cells at R/T what are you worried might happen?  This strain is a lambda lysogen that produces bacteriophage T7 RNA polymerase (correct?). Therefore it stands to reason that you wish to express some foreign gene product under the control of the T7 promoter, so we are talking about a transformation where you already have the plasmid in hand and are just changing hosts.  So you don't need the competent cells to have a transformation efficiency greater than 1EE8 per ug--1EE6 per ug would be more than enough. Leaving them out at R/T _might_ be okay, or it _might_ ruin them.

Comment: I have not transformed the cells yet. I was told to follow a protocol to make the cells competent before transformaton. In a few hours I will be cleaning the cells and planning to perform transformation. Also, wouldn't putting the cells in 4 degrees Celsius form ice and cause damage to the cells upon thawing?

Comment: 4 C° is fridge temperature, above the freezing point of water. Are you thinking of 4F° or perhaps -4C°?

Comment: Yes, I know it is fridge temperature, which is why I was worried that it could freeze and damage the cells upon thawing. The overnight cells ended up alright, although their growth curve lagged a bit, but overall it was OK. Thank you all for your inputs.

Comment: Pure water freezes at 0C, but the buffer that render the cells competent for DNA transformation contains divalent cations (usually Ca++). These ions will cause freezing point depression (like sprinkling rock salt on an icy sidewalk). So I would not expect the bacterial cells to freeze until the temperature was well below 0C. You also need to take into account that the bacterial cells contain lots of ions (all of the proteins, for example) and is about 150 mM in total (various physiological ions). Finally, if your recipe includes glycerol that also depresses the freezing point further.